# How to send an image file store in a variable to php using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send an image file to PHP file using jQuery, by first storing the image in a variable and then send it for processing. The php code outputs an error like this:

**Undefined index: img in C:\xampp\htdocs\edash\admin\checks\a_addQuest.php on line 2**

This is the html code.

```
<input type="file" name="img" id="img">
```

This is my js code.

```
$("#submitQuest").click(function() {
    var  dataString;
    var img  = $("#img")[0].files[0];
    dataString   = "img="+img;

    $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url  : "../admin/checks/a_addQuest.php",
       data : dataString,
       success: function (result) {
            $("#output").html(result).fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $("#output").fadeOut(3000);
        });
     }
  });
  return false;
});
```

And This is the php file.

```
<?php
     $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
     if($img){
           echo "working";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#submitQuest").click(function() {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#img')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url  : "../admin/checks/a_addQuest.php",
       data : data,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (result) {
          $("#output").html(result).fadeIn("slow", function () {
              $("#output").fadeOut(3000);
          });
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hello Ryan, you know the image file is sent with other data through the `dataString` variable.  I want to maintain the dataString and not `new formData()`. So i want a way I can receive the object file send to PHP file.